# Adding multiple annotations of same type c# charting

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I am attempting to add multiple flags of similar types (arrows) to a live chart using a C# windows forms project. This is to provide a label when a value falls out of a pre-defined specification.
I am currently stuck in how to create new instances of the ArrowAnnotation class so if multiple events happen there will be multiple flags for the people checking the chart. I am able to create one instance and manipulate the position to the latest data point in the series (it shouldn't be a stretch to lock it to a historical point, I just haven't done that yet.)

I have an understanding of creating multiple instances of other classes and keeping track of them with lists/ dictionaries but this one has me stumped (or maybe I don't have as good an understanding as I think?)

I can't share the code I have directly but I think I can write some example code if needed.

edit-

I am looking into using a memberwise clone to copy common attributes of each arrow and add those objects to a dictionary.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have managed to figure out how to do this for my use case.

When updating the live chart I can call a method if a parameter falls out of specification. In that method I create a new instance of the annotation, and the properties that I want to use as a template. (these values can also be changed with conditional logic if you want slight variation, and can be passed in with the argument) than add that newly made annotation to the annotation group. I am still looking for improvements to the code. I am still wanting a way to assign a name to the arrow, than recall that one and modify it (if I wanted to). And change the pass/fail criteria than apply annotations for the new failure points (but that is going into new territory)

```
     // This is not the full method just the part that counts for this question.
    private ArrowAnnotation floatArrow;
    private void UpdateChart()         
    {

        GenerateArrows(dateTime, sensorValue);
        this.chart1.Annotations.Add(floatArrow);enter code here      
    }

    private void GenerateArrows(DateTime x, double y)
    {
        floatArrow = new ArrowAnnotation();
        floatArrow.Name = Convert.ToString(x);
        floatArrow.ToolTip = Convert.ToString(x);
        floatArrow.AxisXName = "ChartArea1\\rX";
        floatArrow.AxisYName = "ChartArea1\\rY";
        floatArrow.X = x.ToOADate();
        floatArrow.Y = y;
        floatArrow.Height = 5;
        floatArrow.Width = 0;
        floatArrow.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
```